# Convert Raw[16](Guid) in Oracle to uniqueidentifier in SQL Server by SSMA

Tags: sql-server, oracle, guid, uniqueidentifier, sql-server-migration-assi

I have dealt with the problem that I need to convert data from the `Oracle` database to the `SQL Server` database and there is no way except SQL Server Migration Assistant.
In `SSMA` there is a `TypeMapping` which allows you to define types you want to cast. I added Raw[16](Guid in Oracle) to UniqueIdentifier(Guid in oracle) as `TypeMapping`.
But when SSMA started to convert data it returns this exception:

> The given value of type Byte[] from the data source cannot be
>   converted to type uniqueidentifier of the specified target column.

Comment: Can you convert the RAW value to VARCHAR2, then map the VARCHAR2 to uniqueidentifier? Just a thought...

Answer (score 2):

[ORACLE SYS_GUID](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions168.htm) is RAW(16) and it is 32 character hexadecimal representation.

The equivalent, SQL Server datatype Uniqueidentifier, is 16 byte binary value, which is 36 character representation. 
[SQL Server UniqueIdentifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, in which each x is a hexadecimal
>   digit in the range 0-9 or a-f. For example,
>   6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF is a valid uniqueidentifier value

You can think of below options:

- I would suggest you to use VARCHAR(32) to represent corresponding ORACLE GUID in SQLServer in the typemapping.
- you can have a default value for [NEWID()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for the target column, values will get assigned when you load the data
- Have the target datatype as `VARCHAR(36)` and once you are done with migration, you can start using NEWID() for future values. As GUIDs are going to be unique, you will not face issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @uniqORAconvMS varchar(32) = '5cf5d1b5db12d38067affb261d9619dc'

SELECT left(@uniqORAconvMS,8) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@uniqORAconvMS,9,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@uniqORAconvMS,13,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@uniqORAconvMS,17,4)  + '-' + RIGHT(@uniqORAconvMS,12)

-- xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
-- 5cf5d1b5-db12-d380-67af-fb261d9619dc

-- With TRY_CONVERT to check valid uniqueidentifier
SELECT TRY_CONVERT (UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, LEFT(@uniqORAconvMS,8) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@uniqORAconvMS,9,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@uniqORAconvMS,13,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@uniqORAconvMS,17,4) + '-' + RIGHT(@uniqORAconvMS,12))
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58412202/edit) your post. Don't post on comment section.

Comment: This was helpful to me because we were doing a similar operation but going from SQL Server to Oracle and the addition of the hyphens above clued me in that I need to replace/remove the hypens in the string beforehand for the value to insert correctly into Oracle RAW(16) using HEXTORAW(). gracias!

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Martin is slightly incorrect. If you use entity framework, you'll notice the GUIDs returned from oracle aren't just split up by dashes, but also reordered. So `5cf5d1b5db12d38067affb261d9619dc` should become `b5d1f55c-12db-80d3-67af-fb261d9619dc`, not `5cf5d1b5-db12-d380-67af-fb261d9619dc`.

```
DECLARE @uniqORAconvMS varchar(32) = '5cf5d1b5db12d38067affb261d9619dc';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@uniqORAconvMS,7,2) + SUBSTRING(@uniqORAconvMS,5,2) + SUBSTRING(@uniqORAconvMS,3,2) + SUBSTRING(@uniqORAconvMS,1,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@uniqORAconvMS,11,2) + SUBSTRING(@uniqORAconvMS,9,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@uniqORAconvMS,15,2) + SUBSTRING(@uniqORAconvMS,13,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@uniqORAconvMS,17,4)  + '-' + RIGHT(@uniqORAconvMS,12);
```